# How to log out from an Azure app-proxied website

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, active-directory

I have an IIS website on a server internal to my domain that is also published via azure application proxy, which is secured using windows authentication. Our AD structure is hosted locally and published to Azure AD via AD connect.

Users visiting from outside the domain are authenticated first via the login.microsoftonline.com page.

My problem is that users external to the domain are on shared devices and need to change users occasionally, and I can't figure out how to do that.

I have read that navigating to an url like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/logout?client_id={client id}&post_logout_redirect_uri={???}` is supposed to achieve this, but after arriving at the login page and logging in as a different user, when we return to the site the user turns out not to be the user that authenticated, but remains the same user as before the attempt to change the user.

I have also read that deleting the cookies named like `AzureAppProxyUserSessionCookie`, `AzureAppProxyAnalyticCookie` and `AzureAppProxyAccessCookie` can help, but doing so does not seem to make any difference.

I thought that perhaps the browser was auto-authenticating or pre filling in forms etc, but turning those features off does not affect anything.

My questions are:

- Are any log-off / log-on via Azure AD event logs kept that I can view, and if so, where?
- How are you meant to log-off for my scenario?

Comment: We have a similar situation with users externally authenticated via Azure AD coming into our site, but frequently sharing devices and we're just working our way through it now. Did you get to the bottom of this? It sounds like your users are signing out of Azure AD but their authentication to your site is still alive. Is there some signout code that also needs to run on your site? We're using OpenID Connect and I've just figured out how to redirect selected users to the Azure AD logout page you mention immediately after signing out of our site.

Comment: We ended up working out that most users would not be sharing devices, which was the original concern. For those that were sharing devices, we mandated they use incognito mode when accessing anything to ensure passwords and form data were not persisted across sessions. Not an ideal situation, but workable for the small number affected.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to  resolve this? I've got the same issue. The user authenticates via Azure AD and then the Azure Application Proxy uses KCD to generate a Kerberos token to a internal app. Now we'd like to to enable the user to log of their Azure AD session specifically on our domain. We've added a logout button which links to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout` ...which does the job, but it logs them out of their Microsoft account entirely, which is a bit overkill. Not sure if there's a way to just sign them out of the context of our app / domain specifically.